# FileNotFound exception thrown when trying to create application-context object using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext on Weblogic server

Tags: spring, weblogic

**Scenario**
There was a requirement in my project to multi-thread calls made to a Webservice. This is implemented using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  (Spring).
As the thread class required values to be fed at runtime, had implemented the code as below -

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
for (DocumentData documentData : documentDataList){
    MinerThread minerThread = applicationContext.getBean("minerThread",MinerThread.class);
    minerThread.setHeader(header);
    minerThread.setDocumentData(documentData);
    minerThread.setBatchSize(batchSize);
    minerThreadExecutor.execute(minerThread);
}
```

**Issue**
In local I have tomcat server and this implementation works as expected. However on Weblogic (on the client machine, I don't have access to Weblogic) when the war is deployed it throws FileNotFound Exception.

As the application context object is created via ClassPathXmlApplicationContext API thought the error was thrown because the location was not under the Weblogic classpath. There was nothing set in the Weblogic server classpath. However even after including WEB-INF/classes in the classpath the same exception is thrown.

**Exception**
2013/01/29 09:19:12,853 [ERROR] RequestQueueListener           - org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [../shared-common-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [../shared-common-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [../shared-common-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

BeanDefinitionParsingException is caused because of the relative path that was added in the Weblogic classpath.

On the Weblogic the file is at the location -
./wls10.3.4/ColorisPPT1/user_projects/domains/Coloris_PPT1_Domain/servers/Coloris_PPT1_AdminServer/tmp/.appmergegen_1336142780924_documentservice.war/WEB-INF/classes

When the war if built (Maven is used) the application-context.xml is placed under WEB-INF/classes folder.

Could someone please suggest how to proceed with this.

Comment: what is shared-common-context.xml? is application-context.xml being imported from shared-common-context.xml and that shared-common-context.xml gets loaded but the application-context.xml is not getting loaded ? There should not be any apparent need to set WEB-INF/classes in the classpath as it implicity is included.

Comment: The shared-common-context.xml file holds the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean. 
The shared-common-context.xml file is imported within the application-context.xml file. The application-context.xml file itself is not being loaded.
Ok, however the application is throwing the FileNotFound exception with or without this value set.

Comment: I am in disagreement that application-context.xml file is not being found. The problem lies that the shared-common-context.xml is not being found in the relative location '../shared-common-context.xml'. The offeneder file may be application-context.xml but the file which is not present is the shared-common-context.xml. Can you verify if that xml is present at the relative location ../shared-common-context.xml

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Yes, the shared-common-context.xml is the file that is causing the issue. 
The application-context.xml file imports the shared-common-context.xml - 
`<import resource="../shared-common-context.xml" />`

Below is the location where the code gets deployed on Weblogic (the code is within a hidden directory inside a temporary folder)
**./servers/Coloris_PPT1_AdminServer/tmp/.appmergegen_1336142780924_documentservice.war/WEB-INF/**

Would this cause the issue?

Comment: This issue is resolved. I had to move the file shared-common-context.xml to the location where application-context.xml is placed, also modify the import statement as `<import resource="classpath:shared-common-context.xml/>`